# sorting cells in table view through buttons

Tags: ios, xcode, api, sorting, tableview

I have a table view with data from API. 
Each cell has several properties. What I want, is to sorting cells by chosen button (these three rectangles).

I dont know exactly how should I do it. I think I need tree methods for that, each for clicked button. But how to deal with sorting and reloading data? 
Thanks for answer.[image]

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    callAlamo(url: urlAPI)
}


func callAlamo(url: String){
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
        response in
        self.parseData(JSONData: response.data!)
    })
}

func parseData(JSONData: Data){
    do{
        var readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .mutableContainers) as! JSONStandard
       // print(readableJSON)
        if let rows = readableJSON["rows"] as? [JSONStandard]{
            print(rows)


            for i in 0..<rows.count{
            let row = rows[i]
            if let name = row["name"] as? String{
                if name.isEmpty == false{
                if let status = row["status"] as? String{
                    if let counter = row["counter"] as? String{

                        items.append(Station.init(place: name, counter: counter, status: status))

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }

                    }else{


                        let counter = "no data"
                        items.append(Station.init(place: name, stationsCount: counter, status: status))

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }

                    }
                }

                }
            }

        }
        }
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }

}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! Cell

    cell.place.text = items[indexPath.row].place
    cell.stationsCount.text = items[indexPath.row].stationsCount
    let num = items[indexPath.row].status
    let value = picDictionary[num!]
    print(num!, value!)
    cell.statusSign.image = UIImage(named: value!)

    return cell
}
```

**Sometimes I get null value from API, and then, I assing value to string "no data".**

```
if let counter = row["counter"] as? String{
     /////code
else{
   let counter = "no data"
   //////
}
```

And I dont want to let these values taking part in sorting process, because they are not numbers. How to do that?

Comment: 1. Press button 2. Sort the data 3. Reload tableView

Comment: @Chris ok, but how to sort it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make three actions for your three buttons and sort the array with it and reload the table after that.

```
@IBAction func sortWithName(_ sender: UIButton) {
     items.sort { $0.place < $1.place }
     self.tableView.reloadData()
}

@IBAction func sortWithStatus(_ sender: UIButton) {
     items.sort { $0.status < $1.status }
     self.tableView.reloadData()
}

@IBAction func sortWithStatusCount(_ sender: UIButton) {
     //stationsCount is looks like number so sort it using compare with numeric option
     items.sort { $0.stationsCount.compare($1.stationsCount, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending } 
     self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

**Edit:** Declare one more array named `allItems` same way you have declared your items array. One more thing I haven't noticed first that you are reloading `tableView` inside for loop so that it will reload `n(o)` times instead of that you need to reload it once after the for loop also before reloading the `tableView` and set `allItems` with your items also you are making too many if condition where you can combine it in once.

```
for row in rows {
    if let name = row["name"] as? String, 
        let status = row["status"] as? String,
        !name.isEmpty {

          if let counter = row["counter"] as? String {
              items.append(Station.init(place: name, counter: counter, status: status))                        
          }else{
              let counter = "no data"
              items.append(Station.init(place: name, stationsCount: counter, status: status))
          }
    }
}
//Set allItems with items
self.allItems = items
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Now change all your button actions like this.

ke three actions for your three buttons and sort the array with it and reload the table after that.

```
@IBAction func sortWithName(_ sender: UIButton) {
     items = allItems.sorted { $0.place < $1.place }
     self.tableView.reloadData()
}

@IBAction func sortWithStatus(_ sender: UIButton) {
     items = allItems.sorted { $0.status < $1.status }
     self.tableView.reloadData()
}

@IBAction func sortWithStatusCount(_ sender: UIButton) {
     //Filter your array first
     items = allItems.filter { $0.stationsCount != "no data" }
     //stationsCount is looks like number so sort it using compare with numeric option
     items.sort { $0.stationsCount.compare($1.stationsCount, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending } 
     self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: @belab Welcome mate :)

Comment: one question, do You know how to handle with sorting stationsCount, where value instead of number, is string "no data"? I dont want to displays these cells

Comment: @belab Don't get your question can you please explain bit more about what you want, Edit your question with some example and expected output from it